# Inserir dados em parte especifica de um arquivo

Tags: php

Estou usando o arquivo base de feed do [google](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/160589?hl=pt-BR&ref_topic=2473799), e preciso alterar as informações de forma dinâmica para gerar um arquivo xml, estou usando essa abordagem, com file_puts_contents(), para colocar as tags `<item>` no arquivo:

```
file_put_contents('feed.xml', $xml, FILE_APPEND);
```

só que o final do arquivo xml tem que terminar com essa estrutura:

```
</channel>
</rss>
```

e o FILE_APPEND está colocando abaixo disso, existe alguma forma de inserir o conteúdo num local específico ou sempre acrescentar o `</channel></rss>` 
    ao final do loop?

EDIT: Xml padrão google:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <channel>
        <title>O nome do feed de dados</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com</link>
        <description>Uma descrição do conteúdo</description>

        <item>
            <title>Suéter de lã vermelho</title>
            <link> http://www.example.com/item1-info-page.html</link>
            <description>Confortável e macio, este suéter manterá você aquecido nas noites frias do inverno.</description>
            <g:image_link>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</g:image_link>
            <g:price>25</g:price>
            <g:condition>novo</g:condition>
            <g:id>1a</g:id>
        </item>

    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: O que seria "abaixo disso"? Se deseja colocar ao final do arquivo, eles não ficariam, de fato, abaixo do resto do conteúdo? Ficou bem confuso essa parte.

Comment: abaixo do fechamento do xml , com as tags channel e rss

Comment: Tem como [edit] a pergunta e colocar como o XML deverá ficar e como ele vem do *feed* do Google?

Comment: Certo, mas o link que eu coloquei é o modelo do google.

Comment: Mas nesse modelo já existem as tags que você deseja inserir. Qual é o código que você está utilizando para gerar esse novo XML e como ele está ficando?

Comment: Eu vou usar um loop para inserir dados do banco de dados.

Comment: Posta ele para tentar deixar o problema mais compreensível. Por enquanto está muito confuso.

Comment: é um foreach simples usando o file_put_contents, o problema é só colocar o fechamento no último laço

Comment: E por quê não coloca fora do laço, depois do mesmo? Só será executado quando o laço terminar.

Comment: nem tinha pensando nisso, vou testar, obrigado rs

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você pretende adicionar inúmeras tags `<item>` seguidas de `</channel></rss>` uma possível solução é:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = '<?xml version="1.0"?><rss >...</description>';
// Coloca o início do xml no arquivo
file_put_contents('feed.xml', $xmlstr);

// itens recuperados do banco de dados
$items = [
            "<item><title>título 1</title><description>descrição 1</description>",
            "<item><title>título 2</title><description>descrição 2</description>",
            "<item><title>título 3</title><description>descrição 3</description>",
];

// Coloca os itens no arquivo
foreach ($items as $item) {
        file_put_contents('feed.xml', $item, FILE_APPEND);
}

// Coloca o fim do xml no arquivo
file_put_contents('feed.xml', '</channel></rss>', FILE_APPEND);

// imprime o conteúdo do arquivo na STDOUT
echo file_get_contents('feed.xml');
```

Comment: Fiz de forma parecida, obrigado pela resposta